# Caffeine: Can't provide CacheWriter to AsyncLoadingCache

Tags: java, asynchronous, caching, caffeine

I'm trying to write a `AsyncLoadingCache` that accepts a `CacheWriter` and I'm getting an `IllegalStateException`.

Here's my code:

```
CacheWriter<String, UUID> cacheWriter = new CacheWriter<String, UUID>() {
        @Override
        public void write(String key, UUID value) {

        }

        @Override
        public void delete(String key, UUID value, RemovalCause cause) {

        }
    };

AsyncLoadingCache<String, UUID> asyncCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writer(cacheWriter)
        .maximumSize(100L)
        .buildAsync((String s) -> { /* <== line 41, exception occurs here */
            return UUID.randomUUID();
        });
```

And I'm getting this trace

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException
>       at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.requireState(Caffeine.java:174)
>       at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine.buildAsync(Caffeine.java:854)
>       at com.mycompany.caffeinetest.Main.main(Main.java:41)

If I'll change the cache to a `LoadingCache` or remove `.writer(cacheWriter)` the code will run properly. What am I doing wrong? it seems I'm providing the right types to both objects.

Comment: Sorry, but the two features are incompatible. I’ll review the builder to clarify that in the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately these two features are incompatible. While the documentation states this, I have updated the exception to communicate this better. In `Caffeine.writer` it states,

> This feature cannot be used in conjunction with {@link #weakKeys()} or {@link #buildAsync}.

A `CacheWriter` is a synchronous interceptor for a mutation of an entry. For example, it might be used to evict into a disk cache as a secondary layer, whereas a `RemovalListener` is asynchronous and using it would leave a race where the entry is not present in either caches. The mechanism is to use `ConcurrentHashMap's` `compute` methods to perform the write or removal, and call into the `CacheWriter` within that block.

In `AsyncLoadingCache`, the value materializes later when the `CompletableFuture` is successful, or is automatically removed if `null` or an error. When the entry is modified within the hash table, this future may be in-flight. This would mean that the `CacheWriter` would often be called without the materialized value and likely cannot do very intelligent things.

From an API perspective, unfortunately telescoping builders (which use the type system to disallow incompatible chains) become more confusing than using runtime exceptions. Sorry for not making the error clear, which should now be fixed.